# Set orientation landscape for a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

My app is a portrait app, now I want to put a view controller in landscape. There's a easy way to do that? I set the device info only in portrait now I've a view controller in which there are a media player and I think it's better to watch this video in landscape mode.
I tried this methods:

- `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate`: doesn't work
- `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`: doesn't works

You know if there's a way to solve this without redo all app inserting category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 things to do :

- Set the supported device orientations on the target info
  [image]
- Set the `(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` method for your viewController. If this view is only supposed to show the video I guess you should only allow `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`.